# Eclipse remote tracking branches are all missing suddenly

Tags: eclipse, branch, git-branch

I used to have many branches in remote tracking.

After I set the GIT_TRACE_PACKET to be 1, change the GIT remote connection timeout to be 6000, import a new repository project down tried for so many times due to premature EOF error, at the end I successfully import the repository.

However, the remote tracking branches are all missing for all the projects including the existing project's remote tracking at the end.

I tried to set the GIT_TRACE_PACKET to be 0 or retry importing the project but it's still the same.
I doubt that maybe some kind of configuration changed and made the remote tracking branches to be missing.

[image: ECLIPSE REMOTE TRACKING]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to command line and check you `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` **[refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)**.

To fetch *all* branches, the refspec needs to be:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If the refspec is:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Then a `fetch` would only bring back the `master` branch.
This is typical of a [`git clone --branch develop --single-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

So change your fetch refspec, do a `git fetch`, and double-check the remote tracking branches with `git branch -avv`.

Finally, switch back to Eclipse and check the remote tracking section.

Answer (score 0):

I found another alternative way to solve this problem. 
 1. Delete the file C:\Users*****\workspace.metadata folder.
 2. Open the eclipse again.
 3. Your eclipse configuration are all reset as origin.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .metadata will remove all the projects from Eclipse and will reset everything. So, best solution is to perform a pull (Right Click -> Team -> Pull) and then try rebasing. If this doesn't work, delete the eclipse project and local repository and the checkout the branch again. Then do a Pull and try rebasing.